# Projection of vector $v$ on $u$ in terms of inner product

Tags: inner-products

$$
\mathrm{proj}_{v}(u) = \frac{\left \langle v,u \right \rangle}{\left \langle v,v \right \rangle}v=\left \langle \hat{v,}u \right \rangle\hat{v}
$$

I am unable to follow from the second to the last inequality. Could someone kindly explain how the last equality comes about?

Comment: seem true, that is how projection is defined, the second equality is definition if $\hat{v}$ has norm 1 (unit norm), and the first one is the same just you normalize ( you make v to have norm 1 ) , norm is $||v||=\sqrt{<v,v>}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This follows from the definition of the norm as $||v||^2=\langle v,v\rangle$ and remembering that $\hat{v}=\frac{v}{||v||}$:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\langle v,u\rangle}{\langle v,v\rangle}v&=\langle v,u\rangle\cdot\frac{v}{\langle v,v\rangle}\\
&=\langle v,u\rangle\cdot\frac{v}{||v||^2}\\
&=\left\langle \frac{v}{||v||},u\right\rangle\cdot\frac{v}{||v||}\\
&= \langle\hat{v},u\rangle\cdot\hat{v}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I see it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$\hat{v}$ is a unit vector in the direction of $v$:
$$\hat{v} = \frac{v}{|v|}; $$
Revoking that $<v,v> = |v|^2$ and property of scalar product $\alpha<a,b>=<\alpha a,b>$ we have
$$\frac{<v,u>}{|v|^2}v = <\frac{v}{|v|},u>\frac{v}{|v|}=<\hat{v},u>\hat{v}. $$